# Why were multiple layers of absorbers and scintillators used in the CMS HCAL?

Tags: particle-physics, experimental-physics, large-hadron-collider, experimental-technique, experimental-technology

Why were multiple layers of absorbers and scintillators used in the [CMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compact_Muon_Solenoid) [HCAL](https://cms-opendata-workshop.github.io/workshop2023-lesson-cms-detector/04-hcal/index.html)? Couldn't they have used just one absorber and one scintillator layer? Why was the choice made to have multiple layers?

Comment: Without even knowing exactly what the experiment is, multiple reasons come to mind. Could you expand on the experiment and what they are measuring and what data they get from the system?

Comment: If you really read about these two stations, you could answer yourself

Answer (score 2):

The CMS HCAL has multiple layers because it is a [sampling calorimeter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calorimeter_(particle_physics)#Homogeneous_versus_sampling).  The multiple layers allow the energy of the shower to be sampled as it grows and then decays.  If you had just one layer of absorber followed by scintillator, all you could do is set a lower limit on the energy of the hadron, i.e. it had enough energy for its shower to penetrate the absorber, but you wouldn't have any idea how much energy was in the particles passing through the single layer of scintillator. I recommend looking at an introduction to calorimetry, such as [this](https://indico.cern.ch/event/518474/contributions/1198681/attachments/1267581/1877122/Calorimetry-lecture-to-Southampton-students-4May2016-Cockerill-compressed.pdf) or [this](https://cds.cern.ch/record/692252/files/ep-2003-075.pdf).